# Syntax Error on my entity with annotation PHP8, but I followed the API platform's documentation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com, symfony5, php-8

I have a Syntax Error on my API platform's project in my entity post,
I don't know if it's doctrine version problem or me.
symfony plateform documentation here

> https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups%5B1%5D

I followed the API plateform documentation, but, I have the impression that doctrine does not accept PHP8 attributes.

What can I do to solve this? I have tried to change the `composer.json` file (require PHP).

ParseError
message: "syntax error, unexpected ','"
code: 0
file: "./src/Entity/Post.php"
line: 20

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\PostRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

//read:collection pour lire une collection d'article
//read:item correspond à la lecture d'un seul item
/*ici je souhaite afficher les attributs title et slug quand je demande une collection d'article mais afficher 
    mais afficher en plus le contennu ainsi que la date quand je fais une requete d'un seul article
*/

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PostRepository::class)
 */
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext:['groups'=> ['read:collection']],
    itemOperations:[
        'get' => [
            'normalization_context' => ['groups'=> ['read:collection', 'read:item', 'read:Post']],
        /*'put' => [
            'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['put']],
        ],*/
        ],
    ],
)]
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    #[Groups(['read:collection'])]
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    #[Groups(['read:collection'])]
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    #[Groups(['read:collection'])]
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    #[Groups(['read:item'])]
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable", nullable=true)
     */
    #[Groups(['read:item'])]
    private $uptdatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="posts")
     */
    private $category;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUptdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->uptdatedAt;
    }

    public function setUptdatedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $uptdatedAt): self
    {
        $this->uptdatedAt = $uptdatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the [ask] guide you must post your code as text, not pictures. There's no reason to use images for them and it's very unhelpful for everyone who is trying to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Use a proper IDE. And read about phpcs/phpstan/php-cs-fixer. It will find this kind of errors or will format your code in such a way you can find it yourself.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?